# What is the runtime & space complexity of this Repeated Substring Pattern code? (Code is written in Java)

Tags: java, string, data-structures, time-complexity, space-complexity

I wrote this solution for LeetCode #459 problem. https://leetcode.com/problems/repeated-substring-pattern/
I want to know the runtime & space complexity of this solution.
I'm assuming runtime complexity of O(logN N) where N is the length of the String. Am I right?

```
    
    public boolean repeatedSubstringPattern(String s) {
        if (s == null || s.isEmpty()) return true;
        int l = s.length();
        for (int i = l / 2; i > 0; --i) {
            if (l % i == 0 && isThisSubString(s, s.substring(0, i), l / i)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    
      private boolean isThisSubString(String s, String subString, int m) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
            sb.append(subString);
        }
        return s.equals(sb.toString());
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

In the worst case when i is 1, m is equal to 5. isThisSubString method will be iterating over the entire string. So Asymptotically in the worst case, it is O(n^2).